# What is the purpose of putting a thread on a wait queue with a condition when only one thread is allowed to enter?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, multitasking

On this request

```
ssize_t foo_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count,loff_t *ppos)
{
    foo_dev_t * foo_dev = filp->private_data;
    if (down_interruptible(&foo_dev->sem)
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    foo_dev->intr = 0;
    outb(DEV_FOO_READ, DEV_FOO_CONTROL_PORT);
    wait_event_interruptible(foo_dev->wait, (foo_dev->intr= =1));
    if (put_user(foo_dev->data, buf))
        return -EFAULT;
    up(&foo_dev->sem);
    return 1;
}
```

With this completion

```
irqreturn_t foo_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    foo->data = inb(DEV_FOO_DATA_PORT);
    foo->intr = 1;
    wake_up_interruptible(&foo->wait);
    return 1;
}
```

Assuming foo_dev->sem is initially 1 then only one thread is allowed to execute the section after down_interruptible(&foo_dev->sem) and threads waiting for that semaphore make sense to be put in a queue.(As i understand making foo_dev->sem greater than one will be a problem in that code).

So if only one passes always whats the use of foo_dev->wait queue, isnt it possible to suspend the current thread, save its pointer as a global *curr and wake it up when it completes its request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to put single thread to wait (using `set_current_state()` and `schedule()`) and resume it later (using `wake_up_process`).

But this requires **writing some code** for check wakeup conditions and possible absent of a thread to wakeup.

Waitqueues provide ready-made functions and macros for wait on condition and wakeup it later, so resulted **code** becomes much **shorter**: single macro `wait_event_interruptible()` processes checking for event and putting thread to sleep, and single macro `wake_up_interruptible()` processes resuming possibly absent thread.